# Run selenium in parallel/scrape multiple sites in parallel or in order?

Tags: python, django, selenium, selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing

I'm new to Django, I'm currently creating a web app that has a form that sends user input from the form to some other online tools, submits that data and then scrapes the results and shows the output in the form of a table on my web app like so: [https://i.imgur.com/AVj3cJJ.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTvQ1.png)

I've ended up using selenium with PhantomJS as the tools have javascript objects, I was using mechanicalsoup before which was working well but got stuck when I got to the javascript elements hence switching to selenium.

I've ran into a problem, currently I run the scraper via a function I've created and call it in my view like so:

```
if form.is_valid():
     crisporDF = crispor(form.cleaned_data['dnaSeq'], form.cleaned_data['species'])
```

This function takes the user data and feeds it into the scraper and then produces the table as can be seen in the screenshot above, all works fine, however I have 5 tools I need to scrape and produce 5 tables, so I've created another similar function for another tool and this is the result I get: [https://i.imgur.com/qDXVR7s.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V41GF.png)

As you can see it kinda works, the results in the second table are fine but using the same input data from the user the first table isn't producing the correct results.

I think? It's because I'm creating a new webdriver in each function, and I know Django is a synchronous framework, but I also know there are ways to run functions asynchronously. I don't know why its not producing the correct results for the first site anymore. But if my logic is correct it must be because one instance of a webdriver can be called at once? I've tried creating one webdriver but it doesn't seem to work.

Hence I am asking,

- how do I run selenium in parallel?
- Or how do I get selenium to go to the first site, run my function and get the data, then go to the next url and run my next function
  and get the data? So in order/chronological? I understand that this
  will increase page load time but that is not something I am worrying
  about as with scientific data processing it can take seconds to even
  hours so that is not a problem.
- I understand there are tools like celery, but since loading times aren't a problem I don't mind running the processes in the
  foreground, would Multiprocess in Python be an option? e.g. create an
  instance for each tool so e.g. 5 instances of the webdriver for each
  tool, get the data then pool it together to print as tables on the
  site? Is that possible?

Thanks for all your help! If you need any more info please ask!

Comment: Hello, did you get a solution to this please?  I'm also interested and was about to ask a very similar question!